# Adding aspell as user defined dictionary to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spell-checking, aspell

The default English dictionary bundled with Eclipse is a bit weak, missing many words that are then wrongly marked as errors. I would thus like to change to a user dictionary; this seems to be possible in the dialogue ***Window*** > ***Preferences*** > ***General*** > ***Text Editors*** > ***Spelling***.

I have tried providing the paths to the `.gz` and `.rws` files found in the `aspell` folders, but Eclipse accepts none. Which file is Eclipse exactly expecting in this dialogue?

Answer (score 1):

The expected spelling dictionary format **is a plain text file with one word per line.**

I'll point to the preference page where it says this right under the text field:
[image: Spelling preference page]

If I sound annoyed, I am. Not by the questioner, but by the people that deleted @greg-449's original answer, who seemed to have little activity in any of the tags on this question, and by SO itself for having them review it.